# Converting a non-associative list of arrays to an associative array of arrays

Tags: php, arrays, associative-array

I have a list of arrays (or objects, they are coming from a database via the `PDO` `fetchAll()` function, so both options are OK for me). I wish to convert the list of arrays to an associative array of arrays with the key of each array being one of its columns.

I can obviously do a loop, but I am wondering whether there is some PHP function which already does this, maybe in a more efficient way.

So to illustrate it, lets say I have an array (non-associative) with arrays inside:

```
[0] => {'name' : 'Joe', 'surname' : 'Bloggs', 'id' : '12345'}
[1] => {'name' : 'Sandy', 'surname' : 'Smith', 'id' : '54321'}
```

I wish to convert it to:

```
['12345'] => {'name' : 'Joe', 'surname' : 'Bloggs', 'id' : '12345'}
['54321'] => {'name' : 'Sandy', 'surname' : 'Smith', 'id' : '54321'}
```

Comment: Do you have objects or arrays ?

Comment: @adeneo I have associative arrays (internally) at the moment, but I can change them easily to objects if needed. Just a question of changing to `PDO::FETCH_OBJ`. So both options OK for me if an elegant technique exists (which does not involve looping).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A simple loop would do, but that's too boring to post an answer for, so here you go:

```
$array = array_combine(array_map(function (array $row) { return $row['id']; }, $array),
                       $array);
```

If you're partial to [functional PHP](https://github.com/lstrojny/functional-php):

```
$array = array_combine(F\pluck($array, 'id'), $array);
```

Comment: LOL :), well yeah not looking for a simple loop which I can easily do. Do you think this is more efficient?

Comment: No, since it 1) loops over the array twice and 2) stores a separate array of ids in memory. You could optimize that with a loop. Probably doesn't make a lot of difference for average array sizes though.

Comment: As far as I know the array_map function needs a "callable" as first param, and an array is not..

Comment: @arraintxo Dayum, right. The argument order keeps tripping me up. :)

Comment: @deceze Functional PHP? Thats not standard PHP right? Interesting though!

Comment: @jbx It's a bunch of functions that implement some functional programming paradigms/primitives in PHP. It *is* all just standard PHP.

Comment: @deceze Thanks. Good to know about it. Unlikely to include them for this small project just for this line, but interesting to learn what they offer.

Comment: @jbx Yeah, I'm a fan of the idea of using the right amount of code to express the complexity of what you're trying to do. *"Use one of the array members as index for the array"* is not so terrifically complex that I'd want to spend more than a line of code on it; functional paradigms help reduce a lot here. :)

Comment: @deceze Is the first line of code correct with the `array_map()`? So that I select your answer as the correct one?

Answer (score -1):

```
$rows = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

or

```
$rows = $stmt->fetchall(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

Let's read what [HashPHP](http://wiki.hashphp.org/PDO_Tutorial_for_MySQL_Developers) said:

> Note the use of PDO::FETCH_ASSOC in the fetch() and fetchAll() code
>   above. This tells PDO to return the rows as an associative array with
>   the field names as keys. Other fetch modes like PDO::FETCH_NUM returns
>   the row as a numerical array. The default is to fetch with
>   PDO::FETCH_BOTH which duplicates the data with both a numerical and
>   associative keys. It's recommended you specify one or the other so you
>   don't have arrays that are double the size! PDO can also fetch objects
>   with PDO::FETCH_OBJ, and can take existing classes with
>   PDO::FETCH_CLASS. It can also bind into specific variables with
>   PDO::FETCH_BOUND and using bindColumn method.

Comment: How will it know which column I want to be the key in the associative array? I think that works on the internal individual arrays (which I am already doing) I am looking at the outer array.

Comment: this will produce his 1st array, not the one he wants!

Comment: As @michi says that would not return the array he wants, just the one he allready has.